# JS - Getting either text or JSON with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I am moving over from jQuery AJAX requests to the new Fetch API (nothing against jQuery, I still have it in my site, but Fetch looks - according to [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/2015/thats-so-fetch/) and [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/fetch) and also IMHO - to be the new way of sending async requests).

As such, with jQuery, I had the following function (more or less):

```
function ajaxCall(type, url, data) {
  return $.ajax({
    type: type,
    url: url,
    data: data,
  })
  .fail(function(xhr, status, errorThrown) {
    // Do fail stuff
  })
  .always(function(xhr, status) {
    // Do always stuff
  });
}

// Later...
var myAjax = ajaxCall(myType, myUrl, myData);
myAjax.done(function(xhr) {
 // Do done stuff
});
```

This way, I could have one function be called to handle *any* and *all* ajax requests I could ever need (for the most part at least...). Note that I do not declare a `dataType`, as I use jQuery's [intelligent guess](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/). This way my server can send me whatever response and I could handle it (probably a smarter way to do this would be to pass another parameter with the data type - in the case the "intelligent guess" goes wrong, but this was the way I set it up).

I am now trying to recreate the above with the new Fetch API. What I have so far currently looks like this:

```
function fetchCall(url, method, body) {
  // This if statement is supposed to handle
  // query selectors (which in GET requests go in the url)
  // on GET requests - as opposed to POST req's which go in the body
  if (method === 'GET') {
     var data = body;
     url = new URL(url, location.protocol + '//' + location.host + '/');
     Object.keys(data).forEach(key => url.searchParams.append(key, data[key]));
     body = undefined;
  }
  return fetch(url, {
    method: method,
    body: body
  }).then(function(res) {
    if (res.ok) return res;
    throw new Error('Server error. Status code: ', res.status);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}

// Later...
var myFetch = fetchCall(myUrl, myMethod, myBody);
myFetch.then(function(res) {
  console.log(res);
});
```

The problem I am running into is that `if res.ok return res;` does not state what type of response it is (i.e. `res.json()`, `res.blob()`, `res.text()`, etc.).

> Thus, I am wondering how to set up a dynamic way of setting the type of response body. Is this even possible at the Fetch API's current state of development? Is it just that there is something I am not duplicating in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)?

**After messing around with this, I also realized I could make it always set to `return res.text();` and the if the call is supposed to be JSON, use `JSON.parse(response);`, but I do want it to be dynamic. What if I end up wanting to return a `blob()`?**

Comment: It is very unusual that you don't know what `Content-Type` of response you're getting. Typically, you do, and a typical API endpoint is consistent in its content type, given requested content type. Making your code too universal is more likely an anti-pattern. Is it even critical to do that?

Comment: @RishatMuhametshin you bring up a good point. I do want to implement this function into my Fetch "black-box" (if you could call it that). Is `Content-Type` the answer to my question? Or at least a part of it? If so, maybe you could elaborate in an answer below. Tks

Comment: Yes, exactly. Let me write it in form of an answer.

Answer (score 3):

So, as far as the conversation has reached, there is a way to understand what type of content has been received, with two remarks:

1. Typically you have to always know and expect exact content type, and a universal solution is rather odd in case of fetching from a certain remote endpoint, and
2. The `Content-Type` header is what will tell you the type of content received, but the server may send a wrong header, which is very unusual to happen and therefore is negligible.

The [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) object has `header` property that is (kind of) a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), so you can use its `get` method to get a value by key.

The easiest and cleanest way to check if the returned value is a certain MIME type you expect is by using a regular expression:

```
// replace url with the actual API endpoint URL
fetch(url).then(response => {
  const contentType = response.headers.get('Content-Type'); // -> "text/html; charset=utf-8"

  if (/text\/html/i.test(contentType)) {
    // do something when the Content-Type is text/html
  } else if (/application\/json/.test(contentType)) {
    // do something when the Content-Type is application/json
  } 
  // and so on, for every Content-Type you need.
}).catch(error => {
  // do something when error happens
});
```